# Azure Web Jobs unable to read configuration of Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I am currently deploying a C# console app as a Continuous Azure Web Job to an Azure App Service and I am using the Azure Web Jobs SDK 3.X(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to).

The Web Job successfully deploys to the Azure App Service but the status of the Web Job is "Pending Restart". When I check the logs, the error I see is that a configuration value is being read in as NULL.  I am setting this value in the App Service's configuration/Application Settings page but it seems my Web Job is unable to read it. Do these settings need to be set during deploy? Or do I need to be setting these configuration values in a different location?

Comment: are you reading using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable?

Comment: Yes. I believe I actually resolved it. My issue was that my app thought that my environment was Develop and it was looking for the appsettings.Development.json file. Once I corrected that issue, it looks like I am reading in my app settings correctly.

Comment: hey, could you please post this as an answer so that would be helpful for other community members who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my app thought that my environment was Develop and it was looking for the appsettings.Development.json file. Once I corrected that issue, it looks like I am reading in my app settings correctly.